# This is a problem that I encountered in elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How should I prove that $\dbinom{2n-1}{n}=\dfrac{(2n-1)!}{n!(n-1)!}$ is odd or even according to whether $n$ is, or is not, a power of $2$?
I'm incapable of doing anything with this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem) tells you that this binomial coefficient is odd if and only if in the (base 2) addition of $n+(n-1)$ there will be no carries. It is easy to see that this can only happen when $n$ is a power of two.

Comment: It's not _that_ difficult to count the number of factors $2$ in the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: Another theorem that yields the same result is Kummer's theorem

Comment: Could you tell us more of the context of the problem? This will help us to know the level of mathematics you want in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote for prime $p$
$$
\nu_p (m) = \max\{s: p^s| m\}.
$$
It's enough to compute $\nu_2\dbinom{2n-1}{n}$. If it equals to $0$ then $\dbinom{2n-1}{n}$ is odd, otherwise it's an even number.

Then we can use direct application of Legendre's formula (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula for details). It says that
$$
\nu_p(n!) = \frac{n-s_p(n)}{p-1},
$$
where $s_p(n)$ denotes the sum of the standard base-$p$ digits of $n$.

For $p=2$ we have
$$
\nu_2\dbinom{2n-1}{n} = \nu_2((2n-1)!)-\nu_2((n!))-\nu_2((n-1)!) = 
$$
$$
=\big(2n-1 -s_2(2n-1)\big) - \big(n-s_2(n)\big) - \big(n-1 - s_2(n-1)\big) = 
$$
$$
= s_2(n)+s_2(n-1) - s_2(2n-1).
$$
It remains to prove that $s_2(n)+s_2(n-1) - s_2(2n-1)$ equals to zero if and only if $n$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: Suppose $n = 2^m$. Then $s_2(n)=1$,$s_2(n-1) = m$,$s_2(2n-1) = m+1$. Do you know how a power of two looks like in binary notation?